# rendering pdf files javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using the PDF.js and accurate bilbioteca render a pdf file in a Windows8 application, however, is giving invalid url.

PDFJS.getDocument("C:/Users/flemos/Desktop/Matérias/cronograma (2).pdf");

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: That certainly doesn't look like a valid URL.

Comment: which would be a valid url

Comment: @Felipej.lemos "http:// mi-servidor-web.com/Matérias/cronograma(2).pdf"

Comment: can not be that way , do not use url server, step the path of the machine directory

Answer (score 1):

Based on "in a Windows8 application" in short problem description, you cannot "force" web browser (at least IE) to load files from the local file system.

Use your custom application code to load the file and pass it in the PDF.js as array -- PDFViewerApplication.open accepts Uint8Array. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx